# Waiting to render another elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I attached an image to can exemplify the problem. I have 4 elements in page:

- a table (which is an header with some data)
- a chart
- a table under the chart (which use chart labels as table header)
- a footer

Because first `table` have only 2 rows (and is static), `tableChart` also is static (with only 5 rows) and the `footer` have only one row, I want to calculate dynamically the height of the chart.

So, I get `window.height` (or container) and decrease `table` height, `tableChart` height and `footer` height. Then, assign the value to `chart` element. I do this inside `AfterViewInit` lifecycle (I tried also `DoCheck`), but can't solve a problem: because #chart element is rendering in same time with the rest, when I get `#chartTable` height inside `setChartHeight()` method, it get only a part of total height necessary to render all 5 rows, so the chart will have a bigger height than the necessary.

To be more specific:

- `chartTable` have an normal height of 100px;
- because the `setChartHeight()` is called too early, `chartTable` is found having only 20px (I think can render only first row)
- so, from the total of 500px (example) will decrease only 20px, instead of 100px and the `chart` height will be 480px (instead of 400px)

How can I wait to render all elements out of chart, and just at the final, to calculate the height of it in a right mode.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.setChartHeight();
}

setChartHeight(): void {
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  if (typeof container == 'undefined' || container == null) {
    return;
  }

  let table = document.getElementById('table');
  let chartTable = document.getElementById('chartTable');
  let footer = document.getElementById('footer');

  const height = container.clientHeight - table.clientHeight - chartTable.clientHeight - 
  footer.clientHeight;

  let chart = document.getElementById('chart');
  chart.style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

Another problem which I think exists is that `chart` and `chartTable` have same data source. So, when the source will came, because the `chart` element is above `chartTable` element, it will be rendered first. So, I need to render chart`only when I'm sure that`chartTable` is already displayed on the page.

edit: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-bird-d835z?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

thanks

[image: Template]

Comment: can you make that in codesanbox

Comment: If your layout breaks use CSS.

Comment: Yes you should be using CSS to solve this problem not JS

Comment: I added a codesandbox example. Being a live dashboard, I need it to be fit on scrensize, so any overflow bar can not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, how Strella and Liam said, I found a solution using `css` and avoiding reuse `flex-layout` library.

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.table {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.chart-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;

  &__chart {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  &__table {
    flex: 0 1 100px;
  }
}
```